# App Crash after signing app with resource shrinking and Proguard

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, proguard, android-proguard

This is the first time I got this type of exception while building a signed APK. I searched a lot but could not find any useful information to fix this.

Any information will help me a lot. Because I already spend a lot of time fixing this. I also want to reduce the APK size.

I am creating a signed APK with below release settings and proguard

```
release {
    minifyEnabled true
    shrinkResources true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```

Proguard:

```
-dontwarn okhttp3.internal.platform.*
-dontwarn java.nio.file.*
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn kotlin.Unit
-dontwarn retrofit2.-KotlinExtensions
```

After building a signed APK, I tried testing that and found that google and facebook login is not working (I am not using any other way to log in) and also app crash when I open Privacy policy or Terms Activity which request an API endpoint using Retrofit 2.

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
```

Below is the logcat of the crash.

```
2018-12-31 15:24:42.054 15126-15126/com.sathi E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.sathi.c.a.i$a.a()' on a null object reference
        at com.sathi.activities.PrivacyPolicyActivity$1.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.sathi.c.d$3.a(Unknown Source)
        at d.h$a$1$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
2018-12-31 15:24:42.281 15126-15126/com.sathi E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sathi, PID: 15126
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.sathi.c.a.i$a.a()' on a null object reference
        at com.sathi.activities.PrivacyPolicyActivity$1.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.sathi.c.d$3.a(Unknown Source)
        at d.h$a$1$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

I don't know what is the cause of this exception. Any information will help. Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

These are the Java Compile Warning which I am getting while building a sign APK file without Proguard but keeping `minifyEnabled true`.

[image]

**Answer:**

Thanks to Reaz's Answer
The issue was the model class which I used to get the response from Retrofit

I added below line in my Proguard

```
-keepclassmembers class com.sathi.models.** { *; }
```

Comment: Check the proguard output for any errors.

Comment: How to check that?

Comment: The output you get when you build the project. Proguard usually spits a lot of messages into the build log.

Comment: Thanks, @Henry for your reply, I've updated my question. Are you talking about these messages?

Comment: Use `-dontwarn okhttp3.**` instead of `-dontwarn okhttp3.internal.platform.*`

Comment: Thanks @EktaBhawsar, but still the same problem...

Comment: Just for once write this line `-keep class com.sathi.activities.** { *; }`

Comment: Thanks, @EktaBhawsar, but in my case, the issue was with my models. I added *-keep class com.sathi.models.** { *; }* and my issue solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to keep the classes. Turning the warnings down will not keep the classes and will shrink accordingly by proguard. In that case, the libraries from Google or Facebook might behave incorrectly.

Same thing goes for the classes used to call the APIs. When you are trying to serialize the JSON data from your API response into a class, the class members should have the exact names where the values returned can be mapped correctly.

I am sharing the rules from my project for your reference. Hope that helps!

```
-keep class com.google.** { *; }
-keep class com.github.** { *; }
-keep class com.android.** { *; }
-keep class junit.** { *; }
-keep class com.example.com.mymodels.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class com.example.com.mymodels.** { *; }
```

From your logcat, I think the model classes that you are using for parsing the responses from your API is causing the error. Can you please keep the classes and let me know if that crashes your program?

Comment: Thanks, @Reaz for your reply. but I also need to reduce the size of the app. I also updated the question.

Comment: The idea is to keep the files related to the libraries that you are using. Shrink the other classes as well as resources to keep your apk size at the minimal state.

Comment: This configuration seems to keep way too much.

Comment: This is to provide an idea of keeping the libraries out of shrinking. I am not suggesting any exact configuration.

Comment: And also, I suggested keeping the pojos which are used for parsing the API response if necessary.

Comment: But I am not sure which library cause this issue.  and as @Henry said a lot configuration is needed. There should be an alternative and easy way to fix this...

Comment: From your logcat, I think the model classes that you are using for parsing the responses from your API is causing the error. Can you please keep the classes and let me know if that crashes your program?

Comment: Thanks @ReazMurshed, Yes It worked. it was the issue of Models which I used to get response from Retrofit.

Comment: Great to know that I could help you. You are most welcome!